# Вопрос по ajax в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Объясните, почему работает так, а не иначе:
есть в html документе тег script, внутри этого тега находится следующее:

```
        $.getJSON(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry&apikey=80b87e96&type=movie&page=1`, function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
        });
```

Здесь все отрабатывает нормально.

Потом я пишу такой же запрос на сервер, но только в функции:

```
 function search() {
        $.getJSON(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry&apikey=80b87e96&type=movie&page=1`, function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
        });
}
```

**search()** срабатывает при нажатии кнопки. 
И он не выводит в консоль ничего.

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что search срабатывает при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: есть форма, у формы: <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Search" readonly onclick="search()">

Comment: вы уверены что сама форма не оправляется на сервер и сама страница при этом не перегружается?

Comment: @teran, в общем, нашел ошибку. Только не понимаю, почему так происходило: если я в теге button у формы делаю тип submit, нажимаю на эту кнопку, то в консоль ничего не выводит. Но, если я делаю тип button, нажимаю на кнопку то все работает корректно. Как так?